# Should I remove the lens hood from lenses that I put in my bag?

Tags: equipment-damage, storage, lens-hood, equipment-storage

Is it ok to always have the lens hood mounted on a lens, even when carrying a camera in a bag or is it in any way dangerous? Can I have the lens hood mounted all the time or should I put it on only when taking pictures?

Comment: Most bayonet hoods can be reversed on the lens for storage.

Comment: I don't think anyone can answer this question only yourself. Basically you're asking whether you can store your lens and lens hood without damaging them. Only you can say.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the bag is subject to enough force to damage the hood, then I'd be worried for the lens/camera. There should be no problem leaving the hood on, however it can take up a lot more space. For this reason most hoods can be reversed for storage.

If they can't be reversed, I often take the hood off and place it loose around the lens for extra protection.